# Product of a specific $(0,2)$ and $(2,0)$ tensor (Minkowski Metric tensor)

Tags: tensors, index-notation

How to calculate
$$\eta_{\mu\nu}\eta^{\mu\nu}$$
Where
$$\eta=\begin{bmatrix} -1  \\ &1 \\&&1\\&&&1\end{bmatrix}$$
All other entries are $0$.

Comment: I don't understand where "But this is wrong since ..." comes from. Why is the equation following that not compatible with your result (which I believe is correct)?

Comment: Your last equation will become correct when you set $\gamma$ equal to $\mu.$ Then what is the trace of $\delta?$

Comment: @joriki yeah, I was following a YT lecture and I had a misunderstanding of what the lecturer was saying, indeed the answer is 4 and not 2 which I assumed it to be, hence the question. I'll edit this post into a Q&A format now. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you for pointing out the error, also please refer to my above comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Writing $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ as
$$\eta^{\mu\nu}=\eta^{\mu\alpha}\eta^{\nu\beta}\eta_{\alpha\beta}$$
Thus
$$\eta_{\mu\nu}\eta^{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}\eta^{\mu\alpha}\eta^{\nu\beta}\eta_{\alpha\beta}$$
Rearranging
$$\eta_{\mu\nu}\eta^{\mu\nu}=\eta^{\mu\alpha}\eta_{\alpha\beta}\eta^{\nu\beta}\eta_{\mu\nu} \\ =\eta^\mu_\beta \eta^\beta_\mu=4$$
Or equivalently since
$$\eta^{\mu\nu}\eta_{\mu\chi}={\delta^\nu}_\chi\,$$
Where $\delta$ is Kronecker delta.

Substituting $\chi=\nu$ we get 4. Note that this only works because $\eta$ is symmetrical.

Comment: In $\eta^{\mu\nu}\eta_{\mu\chi}=\delta^\chi_\nu$ you cannot have  upper $\nu$ on the left and lower on the right. Ditto with $\chi$. Index notation is easy but not forgiving sloppyness.

Comment: @KurtG. I hope its correct now

Comment: Looks OK. Even better would be ${\delta^\nu}_\chi\,.$ You will soon deal with tensors where that matters.

Comment: @KurtG. Done, thank you very much for being so patient.